# Para que serve o !=?

Tags: c#

Para que serve o `!=` no C# e como posso utilizar adequadamente? Visualizei um exemplo em uma estrutura de repetição com `for`, no entanto não entendi muito bem a função dele.

```
int soma = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 != 0)
    {
        soma += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `!=` seria: não é igual a, diferente de, etc ... basicamente o contrário de `==`

Comment: É o operador binário de desigualdade.  Sugerido: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czs2584d.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em c# `!=` é um operador relacional que significa "diferente de".

Outros operadores relacionais são `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, que significam igual, menor que, maior que, menor ou igual e maior ou igual respectivamente.

São usados para fazerem condições com os comandos `if`, `while`, entre outros.

Alguns exemplos podem ser encontrados aqui: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_relational_operators.htm